# Align divs to the bottom

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I have to appends divs into another div with position absolute(can't be relative) to the bottom, the code looks like

```
<div style="position:aboslute; top:100px; left:200px; height:500px">
    <div style="height:20px">Example 1</div>
    <div style="height:2px">Example 2</div>
</div>
```

Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `relative` position to parent and `absolute` position to children.

```
<div style="position:aboslute; top:100px; left:200px; height:500px">
    <div style="height:20px; position: absolute; bottom: 0;">Example 1</div>
    <div style="height:2px; position: absolute; bottom: 0;">Example 2</div>
</div>
```

#### Preview:

[image: Align divs to the bottom]

Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vLn32/

Comment: Which browser are you using? I have uploaded a screenshot of the same in my answer.

Comment: I'm on firefox, in jsFiddle I see it like you, but In my site I wont :S but well, I made a dirty fix with javascript thanks anyway

Comment: Just make sure you give a reset. Don't use nasty fix! :P